# Regex don't capture last item to stop at

Tags: regex

I am trying to capture `[dockercloud_servers]` until the beginning of the next `[` (the start of redis_servers). However, I don't want to capture the `[` last bracket.

I tried doing `?:` but I can't seem to omit that last bracket, any ideas?

**Link:** https://regex101.com/r/fYRiJR/1

---

OR:

---

**Regex**

```
(\[dockercloud_servers\]){1}(?:[^ ]+\[)
```

**Content**

```
[dockercloud_servers]
x
y
[redis_servers]
x
x
```

Comment: Why not do `(\[dockercloud_servers\])([^[]+)`... I think the addition of `[^[]+` (in another capture group, as part of the same group, etc) is really all that's needed to get what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to make a Positive Lookahead with `[` at the end as the following:

```
(?:\[dockercloud_servers\]){1}(?:[^ ]+)(?=\[)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/fYRiJR/3

Or alternatively, you can make your code shorter by writing the beginning of the word, and then use `[\s\S]+` to capture the rest until `[`

```
\[docker[\s\S]+(?=\[)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/fYRiJR/4

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
(\[dockercloud_servers\].*)(?=\[redis_servers])
```

https://regex101.com/r/wmBoK3/1